# Python-taking a picture with raspberry pi camera

Tags: python-3.x, camera, raspberry-pi, sensors, gpio

I have written this code to take a picture when it detects motion however when I run the code it prints 'picture taken' but does not save the picture.
I know my camera works as I tested it in LX terminal with the raspistill command. I have also tried changing the path for the file to be saved.
If you can see where i have been going wrong an answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

cam = picamera.PiCamera()
time.sleep(1)
if GPIO.input(4):
    cam.capture('/home/pi/Eaglecam/surveillance.jpg')
print('picture taken')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try putting the print statement in the scope of `if GPIO.input(4)` to see if you have successfully received the signal from the camera.
2. Might not be the cause but you should close the camera after you're done with it. Use `camera.close()` or initialize the camera using `with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:`

an example from its [documentaion](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-file):

```
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
    camera.start_preview()
    # Camera warm-up time
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.capture('foo.jpg')
```